# SQL error: 1364 Field 'XXXX' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

So I have, table courses:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AppDziennik`.`courses` (
  `id_course` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
  `teachers_id_teacher` INT NOT NULL ,
  `end_date` DATE NULL ,
  `about` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `start_date` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_course`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_course_UNIQUE` (`id_course` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_courses_teachers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`teachers_id_teacher` )
    REFERENCES `AppDziennik`.`teachers` (`id_teacher` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

and second table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AppDziennik`.`teachers` (
  `id_teacher` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `about` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `id_class` INT NULL ,
  `rank` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `logins_id_login` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_teacher`) ,
  INDEX `fk_teachers_classes1_idx` (`id_class` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_teachers_logins1_idx` (`logins_id_login` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_teachers_classes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_class` )
    REFERENCES `AppDziennik`.`classes` (`id_class` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_teachers_logins1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`logins_id_login` )
    REFERENCES `AppDziennik`.`logins` (`id_login` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

When I make that insert

> insert into appdziennik.courses
>               (name, id_teacher, about, start_date, end_date) 
>           values ("Math",'7',"Math",'2013-08-01','2014-06-29');

I get that error:

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'teachers_id_teacher' doesn't have a default
>   value

Where I made mistake? How i could fix it.

Comment: The column name in `courses` appears to be `teachers_id_teacher` rather than `id_teacher` - typo in this question or type in your code?

Comment: I trust too much into autogenerate code my MySQL WorkBench. Its calls columns like this(teachers_id_teacher) when i made. Anyway THX

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending an `INSERT` to table `courses`, there is no field `id_teacher` (you want `teachers_id_teacher`). Since you're using a foreign key, that key **must** exist in table `teachers` *before* you `INSERT` a record into table `courses`. Also, you should only be using backticks (`) and single quotes (') in all your statements.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to insert into the courses table for the column id_teacher a value but your not inserting a value for the column teachers_id_teacher. so I would propose to make the statement as followed:

```
insert into appdziennik.courses (name, teachers_id_teacher, about, start_date, end_date) values ("Math",'7',"Math",'2013-08-01','2014-06-29');
```

Sarajog

Comment: Thats make this : Error Code: 1364. Field 'id_teacher' doesn't have a default value